# "greater" functor gives compiler error

Tags: c++, stdvector

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/*
struct greater
{template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const { return a > b; }
};*/

//std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), greater());
int main(){
    vector<int,::greater<int>()> a;
    int x;
    while (cin >> x)
        a.push_back(x);
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());

    for (int b : a){
        cout << b << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

why this is error ?

```
map<int,int,::greater<int>()> a;
```

i have seen some blogs and they can pass but I cannot
I want to know the answer

Comment: Note that your commented-out class is _not_ a template, but one of its methods is. Hence you can't have a `greater<int>` type, it's just `greater`.

Answer (score 1):

A predicate(comporator) required for [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to compare the elements of container. By default it will be [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) does not require a comparator.

You need to correct following line

```
 vector<int,::greater<int>()> a;
```

to

```
vector<int> a;
```

If you want to sort in ascending order you can pass the predicate [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) as one of the argument as follows:

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), std::greater<int>())
```

Comment: i do not konw <functional> before

Answer (score 0):

**You didn't include `functional`**

Look at [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It requires you to specify a type `T`, and optionally, an allocator. You cannot give it a comparator, this doesn't make sense!

As such, declaring a `vector` of type `int` should look like this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on the other hand takes two iterators corresponding to a range, and *optionally*, a comparator. You can sort a vector in decreasing order like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  // Required for std::sort
#include <functional> // Required for std::greater

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

When in doubt, consult [Cpp Reference](http://en.cppreference.com).

Comment: thank you very very much,you konw exactly what i want,i did not include<functional>,i just do not know it~

Comment: can you explain what is function object?

Comment: template <class T> struct less : binary_function <T,T,bool> {  
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const  
    {return x<y;}  
};

Comment: Countered the downvote. It's hard to guess why people downvote when they don't leave a comment. However, I think it could have been because the answer didn't demonstrate how to declare a vector of type int. Only a guess though.